# How to track asp:button click with Google Tag Manager

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Let's say I've got an asp:button on a website which I'm trying to track to count how many times it has been clicked by different users.

```
 <asp:Button ID="SubBtn" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" Text="Sub" />
```

In my code behind I've got a redirect link to a different page.

I'm aware that I need to include something like

```
<a href="#" name="button1" onclick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'button1-click'});" >Button 1</a>
```

Do I need to convert my asp:button to a html button to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use attribute "OnClientClick":

```
<asp:Button ID="SubBtn" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" Text="Sub" OnClientClick="dataLayer.push({'event': 'button1-click'});" />
```

You can read more about this attribute on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx